# Load function is not sending updated data on reload

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

So once the user logs in I set a session cookie. The session cookie is then verified by the handle function inside hooks.server.ts file.

```
// hooks.svelte.ts

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const session = event.cookies.get('session')

    if (!session) return resolve(event)

    const decodedUser = await admin
        .auth()
        .verifySessionCookie(session, true)
        .catch(() => null)

    // If session cookie is invalid then return null
    if (!decodedUser) return resolve(event)

    event.locals.user = {
        user: decodedUser
    }

    const response = await resolve(event)

    return response
}
```

The handle function then sends the user data to the +layout.server.ts using locals.

```
// +layout.server.ts

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ cookies, locals, depends }) => {
    depends('user:changed')
    
    return locals?.user
}
```

The load function just sends back the user data to the component, which i can then access using the $page store or data prop.

I also added a 'user:changed' as a dependency, so when I call invalidate('user:changed'), specifically when the user logs out or logs in, the load function runs again and sends the updated data.

**Issue I'm facing**

Now the issue is that, when I login and refresh, the $page store's or data prop's initial value is an empty object. Because of that I run the invalidate function and that updates the $page store correctly. But when I refresh again I get back an empty object again. However, if I do hard reload the user data is returned correctly in the $page store.

So, it seems like the $page store returns caches the data it receives for the first time and send it back on every subsequent reloads and do not update it.

In my app, I check whether the data prop contains user data, if yes I render the application or the login page. Because on every reload I'm receiving an empty object my app is showing the login page for a blink.

Any idea on why this is happening? Why the load function doesn't return the updated value when I reload?

Comment: You seem to be using some advanced routing that I haven't played around with too much, but I'm wondering if it'd be simpler if instead of using that load function to return a local if you just created a `user` store or something that you `set()` when the user logs in/out and on initial page load from the cookie. That feels like it would be a lot more straightforward than what it sounds like you're doing.

Comment: @Mordred Thanks for your reply! I actually fixed the issue by removing the service worker from my site. It was caching the load data and causing the issue.

Comment: @Mordred And I tried your idea too, but it won't work well for my use case. I have a single route which renders a login page or the app based on user login status. And I also want to server render the login page. So what will happen is once the user loads the site the because of SSR, the login page will load first and flash away and then the app will render. 

Thanks a lot taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had an active service worker which was caching the load data and returning it back everytime I reloaded the site. After I removed it, everything is working fine!